# location.reload() with new query string

Tags: javascript, location-href

I want to simply reload a page with a new querystring as a user fills in settings on a form.  I could use location.href and just redirect them to the same page with the new query string, but I want the user to be able to click back once, to return to the previous page.  By using location.href, each time they change a setting, it adds to the browser history and they end up having to hit back as many times as they change settings to get back to the previous page.

I tried using location.assign() and that seemed to work in firefox when I followed it up with a location.reload() immediately afterwards, but it didn't work in chrome.

Is this possible to do?

TIA

Comment: No. location.reload() will reload the page, period.

Comment: why are you doing this? refreshing the page everytime user fills a field is probably a wrong way to achieve whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut I'm not refreshing after every field is filled out, I'm refreshing after a set of fields has been filled out and a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what browsers you're trying to support you should look into [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method)

So you'd do something like:

`history.replaceState(null, null, location.href + queryString);`

And of course you would fill in the `null` arguments accordingly if needed.

Comment: this seems to just add another record to the browser history which is exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand the question correctly. You're looking for `replaceState`. That is, if I understand correctly now. Updated my answer.

Comment: this is perfect.  I used the replaceState() and then a reload() and it works exactly like I want.  Thanks.